# Distance not big enough polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I am using polar coordinates when placing nodes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, calc}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, >= Stealth, auto, shorten >= 1pt]
            \node[state](low){$L$};
            \node[state] at ($(low)+(60:2cm)$)(med) {$M$};
            \node[state] at ($(med)+(-60:2cm)$)(high) {$H$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The nodes, which form vertices of an equilateral triangle, are not spaced enough compared to when I do `[above right = of *node*`. How to fix this?

Comment: Yes, `above right=<distance> of` makes sure that `<distance>` is the  distance between node boundaries. Here you are talking about the distance between node centers.

Comment: Oh, I was wondering if I could change the distance such that when the nodes are placed, they are spaced between boundaries, not centers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you place the nodes you fix the distances between the node centers. On the other hand, the `positioning` library sets the distance between node boundaries. So we have to add twice the radius of the nodes. One can look it up in `tikzlibraryautomata.code.tex`, where one learns that the `minimum width` of the `state` nodes is `2.5em`. Hence,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, calc}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, >= Stealth, auto, shorten >= 1pt]
            \node[state](low){$L$};
            \node[state] at ($(low)+(60:2cm+2.5em)$)(med) {$M$};
            \node[state] at ($(med)+(-60:2cm+2.5em)$)(high) {$H$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you do not necessarily need calc here. The third node can be just set `right of` the first one, and for the second one we can do what positioning does, but generalize it to arbitrary angles.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
            \node[state](low){$L$};
            \path (low.60) + (60:2cm) node[anchor=-120,state] (med) {$M$};
            \path node[state,right=of low] (high) {$H$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This allows us also to introduce a style

```
angled=<angle> and <distance> of <node>
```

which can be used as in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning,calc}
\tikzset{angled/.style args={#1 and #2 of #3}{%
at={($(#3.#1)+(#1:#2)$)},anchor={#1+180}}}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
            \node[state](low){$L$};
            \node[angled=60 and 2cm of low,state] (med) {$M$};
            \node[state,right=of low] (high) {$H$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thinking about this, at least I would have found this style useful. One can in principle think of writing such a style without the need of `calc` and adding it to `positioning`...